# Kotlin. Function does not exit recursion after return

Tags: kotlin, recursion

I need to decompose the number l into prime factors. For this I use recursion. And when l = 1, the function must exit their recursion and return the string in which the prime factors are located, however, the function continues to work and already according to a principle incomprehensible to me. Please explain what is the problem with my code?

```
fun factors(l: Int): String {

    return if (l == 1) {
        answer
    } else {
        for (i in 2..l) {
            if (l % i == 0) {
                answer += "$i "
                factors(l / i)
            }
        }
        return factors(l)

    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `answer` defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's first mention some issues in your current code:

1. You're mixing semantics, here. What is the contract of your function? Does it return a value, or does it modify a global variable? Pick one, don't do both.
2. You should not use a global variable because it's way harder to follow. Instead, construct your values locally from the current information + whatever the recursive call *returns* to you
3. You're already using an `if` *expression* with the syntax `return if (condition) { ... } else { ... }`. This means each branch of the `if` should just end with an expression, you don't need to use `return` again. That said, in this case the first branch is rather a special case that you want to get out of the way before doing the bulk of the general work. In this kind of situation, I would rather use a *statement* like `if (condition) { return X }` at the beginning and then have the rest of the body of the function unnested, instead of using an `if` *expression* (but that is a personal preference).
4. It is strange to compute the list of factors as a string. You likely want to avoid duplicates and maybe sort them, so a `List<Int>` or a `Set<Int>` would likely be more appropriate. You can always format after the fact using things like `joinToString(" ")`
5. I'm not sure I get the math correctly, but it seems you really will be getting all factors here, not just the prime factors.

Now, the actual cause of the behaviour you're seeing is that you're calling your function recursively with the *same number* at the end: `return factors(l)`. This means that calling `factors(l)` with any `l > 1` will end up calling itself with the same value over and over. Recursive calls need to change some arguments to the function if you don't want it to be infinite.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't really understand what was going on in this recursion, but it's all clear now!

Answer (score 0):

```
fun factors(value: Int, list: MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf()): MutableList<Int> {
  if (value > 1) {
    for (i in 2..value) {
      if (value % i == 0) {
        list.add(i)
        list.addAll(factors(value / i))
        break
      }
    }
  }
  return list
}

(2..25).forEach {
  val factors = factors(it)
  val result = factors.reduce { acc, i -> acc * i }.toString() + " = " + factors.joinToString(" × ")
  println(result)
}
```

Edit: this version is based on @Joffrey's comment below. Plus I decided to wrap the recursive function, now called *fn*, into a function in order to have a clean parameter list for *factors()*:

```
fun factors(value: Int): List<Int> {
  fun fn(value: Int, list: MutableList<Int>) {
    if (value > 1) {
      for (i in 2..value) {
        if (value % i == 0) {
          list.add(i)
          fn(value / i, list)
          break
        }
      }
    }
  }
  val list = mutableListOf<Int>()
  fn(value, list)
  return list
}
```

Output:

```
2 = 2
3 = 3
4 = 2 × 2
5 = 5
6 = 2 × 3
7 = 7
8 = 2 × 2 × 2
9 = 3 × 3
10 = 2 × 5
11 = 11
12 = 2 × 2 × 3
13 = 13
14 = 2 × 7
15 = 3 × 5
16 = 2 × 2 × 2 × 2
17 = 17
18 = 2 × 3 × 3
19 = 19
20 = 2 × 2 × 5
21 = 3 × 7
22 = 2 × 11
23 = 23
24 = 2 × 2 × 2 × 3
25 = 5 × 5
```

Comment: Thank you man! I will try to fix my code but thanks for your solution

Comment: @Khabi This is *your* solution, just cleaned it up a little. I only replaced _answer_ with a list as argument and return value, so that the function is independent of variables needed to be declared outside of the function.

Comment: @lukas.j I think it still suffers from a similar problem here: pick some semantics and stick to it. Here you're both mutating the argument *and* returning a value. This is quite a confusing API IMO.

Comment: @Joffrey That is a good remark. I made an addition to my answer, and I went for the 'mutating argument' version.